Is it possible to roll-up rollupjs as a standalone module?
I'm trying to use Rollup to roll-up itself. The reason for this is that I need to integrate it into another app [a CLI built with vercel/pkg] as a standalone dependency.
In other words, I need to be able to use it in my source code as follows:
// From this: the usual way
import {rollup} from 'rollup';

const result = await rollup();

// To this: 
import defaultExport from './bundled-rollup.js';

const result = await defaultExport();

I have attempted to do this with the following source code:
// source.js

import { rollup } from 'rollup';

// define input options
const opts_input_obj = {
  context: 'globalThis',
  treeshake: true,
};

// define output options
const opts_output_obj = {
  format: 'es',
};

// create bundle
const bundle_obj = await rollup(opts_input_obj);

// generate outputs
const bundle_output_obj = await bundle_obj.generate(opts_output_obj);

console.log(bundle_output_obj);


with the following CLI command:
npx rollup  --input="./source.js" --config="./rollup.config.js" --file="./bundle.js"

When my config is this:
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  context: 'globalThis',
  treeshake: true,
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      preferBuiltins: true,
    })
  ],
};


I get the following error:
[!] RollupError: ../../../../../../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js (10:9): "parse" is not exported by "../../../../../../node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js", imported by "../../../../../../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js".
https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
../../../../../../node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js (10:9)
 8:   Released under the MIT License.
 9: */
10: import { parse, parseAsync } from '../../native.js';
             ^
11: import { resolve, basename, extname, dirname } from 'node:path';
    at getRollupError (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/parseAst.js:282:41)
    at Object.error (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/parseAst.js:278:42)
    at Module.error (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15122:28)
    at Module.traceVariable (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15570:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:13258:39)
    at ReturnValueScope.findVariable (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:7480:38)
    at FunctionBodyScope.findVariable (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:7480:38)
    at Identifier.bind (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:8752:40)
    at CallExpression.bind (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:6208:23)
    at CallExpression.bind (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:10416:15)

When I try this config:
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  context: 'globalThis',
  treeshake: true,
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      preferBuiltins: true,
    }),
    commonjs()
  ],
};


I end up with the following:
[!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) RollupError: ../../../../../../node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node (1:0): Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
../../../../../../node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node (1:0)
1: ����@�
         @��...
   ^
2: 
3: 
   *
    h���/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFound...
RollupError: Unexpected character '�'
    at Object.getRollupError (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/parseAst.js:282:41)
    at ParseError.initialise (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12611:40)
    at convertNode (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:14356:10)
    at convertProgram (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:13673:12)
    at Module.setSource (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15510:24)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19805:13)
  [cause] RollupError: Unexpected character '�'
      at Object.getRollupError (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/parseAst.js:282:41)
      at ParseError.initialise (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12611:40)
      at convertNode (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:14356:10)
      at convertProgram (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:13673:12)
      at Module.setSource (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15510:24)
      at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/Users/obihill/My/Projects/Business/0_meta/1_monofab/3_dev/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19805:13)

Is it possible to use Rollup to roll-up itself as a standalone [ES] module?

This cannot be done because rollup uses native node modules to speed up things. You  can try @rollup/wasm-node, needless to say it is less efficient.

@EstusFlask Thanks for the info. 'Was looking into using a simpler setup with bun.js build. I'll post an update if it works out.
